# 'Order of Operations' for preprocessing in special grouped variables case

Tags: cross-validation, bootstrap, data-imputation, resampling, data-preprocessing

My question relates to the order in which preprocessing steps occur.

The dataset I am working with has a group of special variables. They are each a separate column in the dataset, but it is known a-priori that these variables possess certain shared qualities that are of interest.

Up to this point, I have been building models that predict a response using a few non-special variables and this entire group of special variables. The models that I have been using require hyperparameter tuning, which I have achieved through repeated train-test split and evaluation using the bootstrapB632 rule. As is necessary when doing tuning in this way, any data preprocessing steps cannot be applied before feeding the data into this test-train evaluation process. Instead, the training split must be processed, and then the test set is processed using the parameters learned from the training split. For example, if a variable is to be centered by subtracting the mean of a variable from every individual value, the mean of the variable in the training split would be subtracted from the individual values in both the training and the test datasets.

The special situation that I have to deal with is that my special group of variables is preprocessed as a group. For example, I have been imputing missing values in the group using the mean of all values in the group of variables. In a train-test split situation, I would use the mean of the group of variables in the training split to impute NAs for the group in both the training and testing splits. I only impute missing values in this group of variables.

This has worked well so far, and it makes sense to me. The issue I encounter now is that I have been tasked with 'flipping the script' with regards to the special group of variables. I now need to build models where the response is a single variable from that group. For each of these models, no other variables from the group are to be included as predictors.

The fact that one variable from this group is being pulled out in isolation leads me to my question. How should I go about preprocessing the special variable? I see two sides to this.

One side is to say that because I am not using the rest of the group for modeling, they should not be used in the preprocessing. In this case, missing values are imputed using the mean of only the single column that is being modeled. The order of operations would be to filter the columns, and then preprocess.

The other is to say that the group should still have some effect, even though they are not being used directly in the model. In this case, missing values are imputed using the mean of the group. The order of operations would be to preprocess, and then filter the columns.

I can see valid arguments for both sides. I was just wondering if there was an ‘official’ order of operations that could provide an answer, or if anyone has a solution.